# How to run codedUI test on visual studio build pipeline

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have a simple test case developed by CodedUI:

1. Open run by windows + r
2. Add "iexplorer"
3. Hit enter Navigate to my webpage
4. Do an assertion.

I can run this on my local PC, but is there any way to set up this as a build pipeline at visualstudio.com?

Actually I did that, but I'm getting an error at the "Test Assemblies" stage:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: Unable to find the top level element of the control ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: Unable to find Windows Internet
     Explorer window with 'C&W DASH - Internet Explorer' in the title. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details:
    2018-11-09T17:41:41.6496491Z TechnologyName: 'MSAA'
    2018-11-09T17:41:41.6496660Z ControlType: 'Window'
    2018-11-09T17:41:41.6496907Z Name: 'C&W DASH - Internet Explorer'
    2018-11-09T17:41:41.6497064Z ClassName: 'IEFrame'   
    2018-11-09T17:41:41.6497222Z ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the Coded UI launch methods instead of starting the application with Windows. I think the visualstudio.com might not launch the test in an interaction desktop.

Code example, from [here](http://expert-automation.blogspot.com/2015/02/launch-browser-with-specified-url.html):

```
BrowserWindow oBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri(url));
```

Never the less MS is dropping Coded UI support and advices to switch to WebDriver:

> Coded UI Test for automated UI-driven functional testing is
>   deprecated. Visual Studio 2019 is the last version where Coded UI Test
>   will be available. We recommend using Selenium for testing web apps
>   and Appium with WinAppDriver for testing desktop and UWP apps.
>   Consider Xamarin.UITest for testing iOS and Android apps using the
>   NUnit test framework.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2019